# How to copy all glyphs or characters of a font in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, font-design

I want to display all characters or glyphs included on a font with all variables in illustrator and copy it to a editable table of characters to make a type specimen, the only way i know is select one by one in the glyphs panel, there must be a faster way.

Comment: Why a font management software that is allready capable of this? Anyway there are better ways sure but that depends entirely on your competency level. I mean you could script this but it would be quite the learning experience if you havent done this before.

Comment: You could do it in Excel or LibreOffice Calc.  Just enter the formula =CHAR(ROW()) to the first cell, and drag it down to fill all the cells until you reach the end of the font.

Comment: I am looking for a script or something to do that really, i found web apps like this https://torinak.com/font/lsfont.html that show all characters of the font, but i cant copy and paste it to illustrator.

Comment: The Excel/Calc formula don´t display all ascii characters of the font.

Comment: @jorge in ASCII, the character from 0 to 31 are control characters so they won't display anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy/paste into Illustrator a list of all available characters ([this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) should do it) and than apply the desired font (ex: Font Awesome). You could use the list from that link to copy/paste it to excel to extract only the column with the characters and than copy/paste it to Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called Ultra Character Map.

[Ultra Character Map for Mac](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ultra-character-map/id520265986?mt=12)

It's not free, but it has a lot of different font cataloging features.
And, if you want the character map as a digital file, you can choose one of the print options, and in the print dialog, use the "Save to PDF" option in the lower left.

*** I am in no way affiliated with this software or profit in any way, I'm simply sharing a program that I use for this purpose.